# How to execute a code when the application is launched

Tags: android

I have a litle android application where i would like to execute some code on the application launching.

How can I do this? I am a newbie on the Android developpement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:

```
protected void onStart() 
{
super.onStart();

Your code here.....

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was in a similar situation. I needed to execute a method only once but `onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()` methods didn't work for me because those methods are called when the device is rotated and in another situations.

So I decided to extend `Application` and run that method in the `onCreate()` of my custom application class because this is **only run once per application start-up** and because **the tasks don't require long-running**

Here is an example:

```
public class CustomApp extends Application {
    public CustomApp() {
        // This method fires only once per application start.
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // This method fires once as well as constructor
        // & here we have application context

        //Method calls
        StaticClass.oneMethod(); // static method 
        Foo f = new Foo();
        f.fooMethod();           // instance method
    }
}
```

The next step is tell Android we have a custom Application class. We do it by referencing the custom application class in the 'android:name' attribute of the applcation tag. Like this:

```
<manifest ...
    <application
         android:name="com.package.example.CustomApp">
        <activity>
            <!-- activity configuration-->
        </activity>
            ...
        <activity>
            <!-- activity configuration-->
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

... For anyone to whom this may help you!

Comment: When using the above method, my application will randomly open when users open certain apps on their devices. It would also open when I push notifications to the device.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is a good idea to read the Activity life-cycle before you start to develop.... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Answer (score 0):

In android, start, execution and termination of an application can be thought of as an execution of a state machine. onStart() method is executed by the application the moment android dispatches it for execution for the first time. You can override the onStart function and use your own code in there as follows

```
protected void onStart(){
  super.onStart();
  return_type method1(...);
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read about Activity: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Android doesn't have a concept of application in the traditional sense, but a series of activities.

Put all initialization in Activity's `onCreate()`

Put code that you want to be run at the start of Activity in `onStart()`